# lwc clone an opportunity product using record-edit-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, lightning-recordeditform

I have a LWC called Opportunity Product Manager
which shows all the opportunity products.

Each Opportunity Product is a LWC itself which has 2 buttons: Edit and Clone. Pressing on these buttons open a Modal which contains record-edit-form.

The edit is working fine. However, I try to clone the product by setting the record-id value to null but that doesn't work.

The spinner after submitting the form just getting stuck.

Any suggestions what would be the best way to clone the product?

I thought maybe to create another Save button to the form which will create a record manually but not sure if this is the way.

Thanks

Comment: we had to build similar solution and had some difficulties during that, in the end we just cloned the `record-form` base component from here https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/recordForm and used that to call apex which were leveraging the SObject.clone() method.

Comment: Without adding an MVP Code it will be hard to tell you what is wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting recordId variable value to null what you can do is -
1- Override submit method of record form with **event.preventdefault()** and then make the recordId field to null.

Also, you can use **onerror** attribute of record form to get the error that you are receiving, that will be helpful in debugging things fast.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying !
I have made the  event.preventdefault() and set the Id to null. 
I tried to print errors and the onerror method doesn't get called.

Comment: Hi, I hope you are using like this.

 event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
  const fields = event.detail.fields;
  fields.Id = ''
  this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);

Comment: Ok we have a little progress, form is submitted for no record is actually being created.

            fields = event.detail.fields;
            fields.Quantity = 1;
            fields.Id = null;
            fields.OpportunityId = this.getOpportunityId;
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);

Comment: So now the form is not getting stuck and submitted but no records created.
I even tried to verify the OpportunityId field is set to a specific opportunity Id. but nothing works.

Comment: I found that it just updates the opportunity product to be cloned and not really creating new one. so setting the fields.Id = '' doesn't work.
If I make the component's  record-id to null then the component get stuck after submitting it.

Comment: Can you share your submit method code snippet

Comment: event.preventDefault();
        let fields= event.detail.fields;
            fields.Quantity = 1;
            fields.Id = '';
//            fields.OpportunityId = this.getOpportunityId;
            fields.OpportunityId = '0067Z00000RK9qgQAD';
            this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);

Comment: Have you succeeded to perform clone?

Comment: I tried similar sort of thing some time back. This approach works fine for me.
Another approach could be you can use 2 record edit form one with record id and another with no record id. Render record form with no id on click of clone and hide the other one. I guess this will work.

Comment: Any chance you can make your 1st idea to work? Its better than the second..it really doesn't work.